# Cloudflare + Heroku SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, cloudflare

I have a rails app that is running on heroku and am using Cloudflare Pro with their Full SSL to encrypt traffic between: User <-SSL-> Cloudflare <-SSL-> Heroku, as detailed in: http://mikecoutermarsh.com/adding-ssl-to-heroku-with-cloudflare/ .

I am also using the rack-ssl-enforcer gem to force all http requests to go through https.

This is working properly, except I have the following issues, by browser:

1) Firefox.  I have to add a security exception the first visit to the site, getting the "This site is not trusted" warning.  Once on the site, I also have the warning in the address bar: [image]

2) Chrome: page loads first time, but the lock in the address bar has a warning triangle on it, when clicked displays:

> Your connection is encrypted with 128-bit encryption. However, this
>   page includes other resources which are not secure. These resources
>   can be viewed by others while in transit, and can be modified by an
>   attacker to change the look of the page. The connection uses TLS 1.2.
>   The connection is encrypted and authenticated using AES_128_GCM and
>   uses ECDHE_RSA as the key exchange mechanism.

Safari: initially loads with https badge, but it immediately drops off

Is there a way to leverage Cloudflare SSL + piggyback of Heroku native SSL without running into these security warnings? If not, I don't see much value in the configuration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My apologies for slinging erroneous accusations against Cloudflare and Heroku :-)

Turns out the issue was not the fault of either, but instead that images on the app (being served from AWS S3) were being served up without https.

If anyone runs into this situation, lessons learned across a wasted day:

S3 only lets you serve up content via https if you serve from your bucket's dedicated url:  s3.amazonaws.com/your-bucket-name/etc..

a) I tried setting the bucket up for static website hosting, so I could use the url "your-bucket-name.your-url.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/etc...", and then set up a CNAME within my DNS that sends "your-bucket-name.your-url" to "your-bucket-name.your-url.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/etc...", to pretty up urls

b) this works, but AWS only lets you serve via https with your full url (s3.amazonaws.com/your-bucket-name/etc..) or *.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/etc...", which doesnt work if you have a dot in your bucket name (your-bucket-name.your-url), which was required for me to do the CNAME redirect

If you want to use AWS CDN with https, on your custom domain, AWS' only option is CloudFront with a SSL certificate, which they charge $600/mo, per region.  No thanks!

In the end, I sucked it up and have ugly image URLs that looks like: https://s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mybucketname...", and using paperclip, I specify https: with ":s3_protocol => :https," in my model.  Other than that all is working properly now.